# Grep specific columns, count and write output file

Tags: awk, grep, text-processing

I'm trying to summarize my data and count for specific items

These are human sequencing data and hence very large.

```
#CHROM  POS   ID    REF  ALT    QUAL    FILTER      INFO          FORMAT                            NORMAL                                          PRIMARY
  1    12867  .     C    A       5  q40;bldp;blq    SS=1;VT=SNP;  GT:DP:AD:BQ:MQ:SB:FA:SS:SSC:MQA   1/0:8:7,1:36,39:0:0.0,0.0:0.125:0:5:14.9,16.0   1/0:2:2,0:33,0:0:0.0,0:0.0:1:5:16.0,0
```

To simplify, the data looks something like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7  column8   column9 column10                                         column11
   x      x      x        x       x        x      x       SS=1       x     1/0:8:7,1:36,39:0:0.0,0.0:0.125:0:5:14.9,16.0    1/0:2:2,0:33,0:0:0.0,0:0.0:1:5:16.0,0
   x      x      x        x       x        x      x       SS=2       x     1/0:8:7,1:36,39:0:0.0,0.0:0.125:0:5:14.9,16.0    1/0:2:2,0:33,0:0:0.0,0:0.0:1:5:16.0,0
```

First , I need to count the number how many different SS in column8. There are 5 different types of SS i.e. SS=1 ..... SS=5.
This could be done by grep command and 
I tried

```
grep SS=1 file1.vcf | wc -l
grep SS=2 file1.vcf | wc -l
```

Then I want to count how many "0", "1" , "2" in column 10 and 11 at the position after the 7th colon (:)

This is the part that I'm not sure how to do. I was thinking about using awk but i'm not sure how to specify to look for at specific position (after the 7th colon (:)

```
awk -F ':' '$11==1' #this does command only specifies column but not at specific position.
```

I have 246 files that I want to do exactly the same. How can I apply to all my files and write the count in txt file? I only know how to do it one by one and probably I can cat the count files at the end.

```
for f in *.vcf; do grep SS=1 "$f" | wc -l > ${f}SS1.txt; done
```

Comment: If you/we don't care about the values in the first 7 columns, why are you showing them to us? Make your examples as concise and simple as possible - the less effort you require us to put into helping you the more likely we are to help you. Show the expected output given your sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count how many different values you have in column 8 you can use the typical approach:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR>1{a[$8]++} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
SS=1 1
SS=2 1
```

To count how many different values you have in the 8th position of a `:`-separated string from the 10th and 11th fields, you can use `split()` to slice the string in blocks. And then, use the same approach as above.

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR>1{split($10,a,":"); split($11,b,":"); count10[a[8]]++; count11[b[8]]++} END {for (i in count10) print i, count10[i]; for (i in count11) print i, count11[i]}' a
0 2
1 2
```

You can put all together to get something like:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR>1{count8[$8]++; split($10,a,":"); split($11,b,":"); count10[a[8]]++; count11[b[8]]++} END {for (i in count8) print i, count8[i]; for (i in count10) print i, count10[i]; for (i in count11) print i, count11[i]}' file
SS=1 1
SS=2 1
0 2
1 2
```

If you want to do this for many files, you can either use the loop or -better- work with `FILENAME` and `ENDFILE` to flush the stored information. Try it out and let us know if you face any problem there.